# finding nearby bluetooth devices with swift

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth

I am currently using swift to make an app that can generate a list of bluetooth devices nearby. However, I cannot find any documents that use swift to do that. All of the files are in Objective C and I am wondering if I can just make an objective C file and connect directly to the storyboard? (my project file is in swift).

Also, do I have to include any other library from outside? (ex: serialGATT) or coreBluetooth.framework is good enough?

Comment: You will only be able to discover BLE devices. For this you can use the CoreBluetooth library. Implementing the CbCentralManager delegate functions in Swift should be pretty straightforward.  Refer to the Core Bluetooth Programming guide and the CBCentralManager class reference e

Comment: Now i have set up the bluetooth, and now my BLE device is sending image data. what API function can i use to receive data from the BLE device? In the end I still use objective C instead of swift

Comment: With CoreBluetooth the only data transfer services you have a readCharacteristic/writeCharacteristic.  You will need to break your image down to 20 byte packets.

Comment: can you say more details about it? so you mean every time Bluetooth can only send 20 bytes of data?

Comment: readValueForCharacteristic:  /readValueForDescriptor:   I found these two API but I'm not sure which one should I use in my case. I just care about the data that the BLE device is sending (it is a camera)

Comment: That is correct;  Using GATT (The only profile supported by Core Bluetooth) you need to send approximately 20 bytes at a time. For example - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40636726/nearby-bluetooth-devices-using-swift-3-0

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to import `CoreBluetooth`

```
import CoreBluetooth
```

Add the `CBCentralManagerDelegate` to your controller. (For a simple app I attached it to my View Controller)

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController, CBPeripheralDelegate, CBCentralManagerDelegate {
```

You should create a local variable `centralManager` (or similar) and then initialize in your `viewDidLoad` function

```
    centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
```

Finally you can create a new function called `centralManagerDidUpdateState` which will act as a callback when the Bluetooth state changes (it's always called on startup in your app.

```
    // If we're powered on, start scanning
        func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
            print("Central state update")
            if central.state != .poweredOn {
                print("Central is not powered on")
            } else {
                print("Central scanning for", ParticlePeripheral.particleLEDServiceUUID);
                centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [ParticlePeripheral.particleLEDServiceUUID],
                                                  options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : true])
            }
        }
```

The important call is `centralManager.scanForPeripherals` This will start the scanning process. In my case I'm filtering devices that *only* have `ParticlePeripheral.particleLEDServiceUUID` in their advertising packets.

That should get you scanning and on your way. I wrote a full end-to-end tutorial on how to use Swift with Bluetooth. It will go into much more detail. [Here it is.](https://www.jaredwolff.com/the-ultimate-how-to-bluetooth-swift-with-hardware-in-20-minutes/)