# How to get nearby iPhone and Android device list by bluetooth in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth

I am trying to find a nearby *iPhone* and *Android* device by `CoreBluetooth.Framework`. Somehow I am only able to get a watch and laptop devices. for others, I am getting only an "Unknown device" I am referring to https://github.com/iqvis/BLEManager-iOS link to get the device list.

Comment: Try this way what mentioned in this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40636726/nearby-bluetooth-devices-using-swift-3-0

Comment: @DhavalRaval Thanks for your comment. Seems you are referring to mac os I am looking into iOS App. please suggest me if there is any link for ios app.

Answer (score 0):

Try below links in your code :

[1] You can use Ble3Framework.framework to scan devices and it provides ZeronerBlePeripheral classes and delegates to get list of near by device.

here is link from where you can download the example and sdk for iOS and Android:

```
http://api6.iwown.com/devcenter/tutorial.html

http://api6.iwown.com/devcenter/home.html
```

[2] Example here: https://github.com/androidthings/sample-bluetooth-le-gattserver If you implement the Android app then iOS app will discover the service.